# The reply address 'https://replyUrlNotSet' does not match the reply address 'https://localhost:44300' provided when requesting Authorization code

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-sdks

Getting error when requesting my `DisplayName` from Azure AD

**Framework**: .NET Core 5.0

**Authentication**: AuthorizationCodeCredential

Code:

```
    public class GraphDataHelper
{
    private readonly string[] _scopes;
    private readonly string _tenantId;
    private readonly string _clientId;
    private readonly TokenCredentialOptions _options;
    readonly AuthorizationCodeCredential _authCodeCredential;
    readonly GraphServiceClient _client;

    public GraphDataHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            _ = new Common();

            _clientId = AppSettings.ClientId;
            _tenantId = AppSettings.TenantId;
            string clientSecret = "I pasted secret here";
            var authorizationCode = "I pasted code here";
            _scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

            _options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            _authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
                _tenantId, _clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, _options);

            _client = new GraphServiceClient(_authCodeCredential, scopes: _scopes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public async Task<string> GetFullNameAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _client.Me
                .Request()
                .Select(data => data.DisplayName)
                .GetAsync(); // Getting error here
            return user.DisplayName; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "404 Not Found";
        }
    }
}
```

Error Details:

> AuthorizationCodeCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS500112: The reply address 'https://replyUrlNotSet' does not match the reply address 'https://localhost:44300' provided when requesting Authorization code.
> Trace ID: 413467fb-04a8-4518-ab23-87b16f7ca100
> Correlation ID: 8d89f9d5-dfdf-4226-8234-b1bf6b6ea9fe
> Timestamp: 2022-03-25 13:52:03Z

Comment: You need to configure the reply url in the azure portal. You have to set default client type to public and not use clientid and secret

Comment: `https://localhost:44300` this URL is already there.

Comment: if you are working localhost you cannot use authenticaton. authentication is only allowed when your client is public. so u need to set Treat the client as public to 'true' in azure portal

Comment: @ruben450 Just like my OutLook, and Teams application this localhost application is also successfully getting signed in using our Azure AD user credentials. I just need to get DisplayName and for that, I need an access token. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: I understand but the error message shows an link to documentation and it explicit says that you cannot use. ROPC, device code flow nor IWA instead turn on the feature to treat the application as a public client

Comment: I did but still getting the error.

Comment: try catching your error response in your catch. use a console.log(e.message) or use a breakpoint to look into the exception

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have not specifically enabled a public client application in the Azure portal and are **attempting to do an authentication flow that is only available on public clients**, such as Username/Password, Integrated Windows Auth, or Device code flow.

you have to turn on the option Treat client as public client
[image]

Comment: I did but still getting the same error.